# Powershell Move-Item with array without empty spaces

Tags: arrays, powershell

Trying to move some files using array in powershell.. This is a very simple version of my script but it explains my issue..

```
 $locations = @(
             ("C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\source","C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\dest","1234"),
             ("C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\source1","C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\dest","5678")
   )


Foreach ($value in $locations)
{ 
    Foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $value[0]))
    {
        If ($file.Name -match $value[2])
        {
        Write-Host $value[0]\$file
        }
    }
}
```

Im not really gonna use Write-host but for some reason powershell adds a empty space between the array values

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\source \File_1234_Nr1.txt
C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\source1 \File_5678_Nr1.txt
```

I wan't these variables to be together so the command Move-Item won't complain about incorrect path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the join-path cmdlet:

```
 $locations = @(
             ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\source","C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\dest","1234"),
             ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\source1","C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\dest","5678")
   )


Foreach ($value in $locations)
{ 
    Foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $value[0]))
    {
        If ($file.Name -match $value[2])
        {
        $path = Join-Path $value[0] $file
        $path
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nimizen!